# System.Timers.Timer: How to raise elapsed event after start interval?

Tags: c#, timer

I have simple timer:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
public Ctor()
{
      _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeout);
      _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
      _timer.Start();
}
```

How to make that timer rise `Elapsed` event after `timeout` time expired?
It is for the first elapsed event, of course.

Comment: If you want to rise event to execute event handler, then move event handler code into separate method (event handler should call that method instead) and call this method directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) does exactly what you want , it raises the event after the specified interval elapses. If you don't want it to be recurring (Runs once only), then set the `AutoResetProperty`:

```
public Ctor()
{
      _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeout);
      _timer.AutoReset = false;
      _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
      _timer.Start();
}


private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here runs after the timeout elapsed
}
```

Comment: hm.. i want to wait first timeout! not to elapsed just after Start

Comment: @AdmiralLand This is already the behavior. On first timeout, the elapsed method is called. No need to do anything then.

Comment: @AdmiralLand Do you mean you want to run the code only once ?

Comment: @3615 This answer does exactly that. Run the Elapsed event after the specified timeout and then unsubscribe from the event to prevent it from running again.

Comment: @3615 Because that is what the Timer class does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a timer to be started after an initial delay?  If that's the case then consider using a `System.Threading.Timers.Timer` instead, as follows:

```
int initialDelay = 5000; // five seconds
int timerPeriod = 1000; // one second
var timer = new Timer(_ => MethodToCallWhenExpired(), null, initialDelay, timerPeriod);
```

Alternatively you can use `Timeout.Infinite` and then call the `Change()` method to alter the Timer behaviour after creation.

Sorry if that's not what you were asking though! :)